# Retrieving COM class factory error: 8007007e after hosting in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, com

I have a Web API application which uses a managed dll as a reference.This managed dll referes to COM+ dll using Interops.So this Web API application works fine on localhost, but after deploying it into IIS server I am facing the exception

> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {90865CE9-F9F4-11D3-8FD8-080036DF2204} failed due to the following
>   error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).":null

This clsid is unmanaged dll. I checked the registry and this clsid has been registered in both 32 bit and 64 bit.While deploying in IIS, I even kept enable 32-bit Applications to **true**.But still I am facing the same exception.
So is there any trick I am missing here?

Comment: The registry may be ok, but this errors indicates there is a DLL (probably unmanaged) that cannot be loaded. It could be any satellite/dependency dll. You could try procmon from sysinternals and monitor what files are being searched for.

Comment: Yes,I found that its a Satellite dll. What should be the approach now to solve this exception?.@SimonMourier

Comment: copy it somewhere in your search path https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx